# TFS View All Changed Folders/Files With Filter Options

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are using Visual Studio 2013 with Team Foundation Server 2012.  We are using local workspaces.  We are just moving from another source control program (StarTeam) to TFS.

One of the big things we are missing from StarTeam is the ability to customize our view, and specifically a view of all the local non-current files.  Our projects are enormous with multiple directories and sub-directories.  If one or more files within a directory is out of date the primary folder in TFS still shows Yes under Latest.  This makes some of our users think they are up-to-date when they are not.  In StarTeam we could show all descendants and filter to our hearts' content - based on status, size, location, locked or not, who last changed it, who created it, the check-in comments, dates, times, etc., etc.

The closest thing we've found in TFS is to right-click on the main branch and select Compare.  This almost does what we want, but it has very limited ability to filter and it takes forever.

I tried the [Diff All Files extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c) but that brings up a separate compare window for each different file with the actual differences highlighted.

I have Beyond Compare set up as the compare/merge tool in Visual Studio but that works only for files, not folders/branches.

Is there any native functionality that can do this?  Or an extension?  Or a way to set the external compare tool to compare folders as well as files?  Or a way to get the primary folder to show No under Latest if any files in that folder have changed?  We have a lot of frustrated users and for some reason they're all coming to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know another way to have all the differences between server and local, but my question is: Why? I Mean, I work in the same situation as you, enormous project, many suybfolders ecc, working in a team, and there is never this need, we only do frequent "get latest" :) . Morning, coffee, sit-down, gate latest, start to work :)

Comment: Basically - older users who can't handle change.  :-)     But it is nice to be able to get a quick list of WHAT has changed so if I see a problem during the day it would be easier to track it down to the out-of-date files I saw this morning.

Comment: You can configure Visual Studio to get latest when the solution is opened. Don't know if you can do it globally...

Comment: We would like to see a list of the latest changed files without downloading them.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you an external tool:

[Diff All Files for VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c)

"Quickly compare changes to all files in a TFS shelveset, changeset, or with pending changes."

Seems what you need.

Comment: We have already tried this.  It opens up a separate compare window for each different file with the actual differences highlighted.  We just want a list of which files are different not what the specific differences are.